# Calculate alters density in a large graph in R

Tags: r, memory, igraph

I'm working with a large social network in R (560120 ties). I want to calculate the local density of nodes, as well as the density of their alters.

I achieved the former with the following code snippet, using the package `igraph`.

```
 g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist, directed = FALSE)
 egonet_list <- make_ego_graph(g)

 dat <- data.frame(
    id = names(V(g),
    egonet_density = lapply(egonet_list, graph.density) %>% unlist()
  )
```

However, I run into memory troubles when I try to calculate the network of ego's alters. I try to run the following:

```
alter_list <- make_ego_graph(g, order = 2, mindist = 1)
```

It does work for smaller graphs, but with my network setup, it is eating up all of my RAM (>110GB) and crashing.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this issue in a memory-friendly way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the local density for one node at a time without saving the alter graphs.

```
library(igraph)
library(purrr)
make_ego_graph(g, order = 2, nodes = 1, mindist = 1)


V(g) %>%
map_dbl(~ make_ego_graph(g, order = 2, nodes = .x, mindist = 1)[[1]] %>% 
          graph.density())
```

You can take the code within map and write a function called  `get_alter_density()` and use `lapply` if you prefer.